# I need assistabce displaying json data correctly in my android application

Tags: android, json, okhttp

Hello there i need some assistance. Im fetching json data from news api and im trying to populate a recycler view. The challenge im facing is its fetching the json well but when im populating my recycler view it displays one json object multiple times from one news source over and over again instead of displaying different news from different news source. Here is my method that is fetching the data

```java
public void fetchNewsData() {

        client = new OkHttpClient();
        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request = new Request.Builder().url("https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?apiKey="+apiKey).get().build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                ResponseBody body = response.body();
                bodyString = body.string();
                MediaType contentType = body.contentType();
                Log.d("Response", bodyString);
                return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyString)).build();
            }

            //fetching json data well
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            } // transmission failure callback

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {


                final String string = response.body().string();
                Log.i("cheese", "onResponse: " + string);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Snackbar.make(v,string,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        try {

                            NewsItem singleNewsItem = new NewsItem();
                            JSONObject main = new JSONObject(string);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = main.getJSONArray("sources");

                            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("json fetched",jsonObject.toString());
                                singleNewsItem.setSourceName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                singleNewsItem.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                                singleNewsItem.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                                singleNewsItem.setCountry(jsonObject.getString("country"));
                                newsItems.add(singleNewsItem);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(newsItems, LatestNews.this);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
        });
    }
```

Here is my adapter class for the recycler view

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private  List<NewsItem> newsItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(List itemList, Context context) {

        this.newsItemList = itemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        // Return a new view holder
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setTag(newsItemList.get(position));
        NewsItem item = newsItemList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(item.getSourceName());
        holder.txtUrl.setText(item.getUrl());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
        holder.txtCattegory.setText(item.getCategory());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsItemList.size();
    }

    // View holder class whose objects represent each list item
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtUrl;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public TextView txtCattegory;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
            txtDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            txtCattegory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCattegory);

        }


        public void bindData(NewsItem dataModel, Context context,int i) {


         }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `singleNewsItem` have to construct in `for loop`

news item that you can see is probably last one because you add the same `singleNewsItem` in the `list`. It means your list elements reference same memory address.